# Two Animations on the Same Object Simultaniously in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, code-behind

I have a custom user control. Part of it is a rectangle that indicates selection. I want to animate this after the user draws it. I have the following methods

```
private AnimationTimeline StartRectangleHeightAnimation(Rectangle rectangle)
{
    return new DoubleAnimation(
        SUB_SELECTION_HEIGHT_RATIO * selectionCanvas.RenderSize.Height, 
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
}
```

for the rectangle height and

```
private AnimationTimeline StartRectangleMarginAnimation(Rectangle rectangle)
{
    Thickness t = new Thickness(rectangle.Margin.Left,
        (selectionCanvas.RenderSize.Height - rectangle.Height) / 2,
        rectangle.Margin.Right, rectangle.Margin.Bottom);

    ThicknessAnimation animation = new ThicknessAnimation(t, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    animation.EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase()
    {
        EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut,
        Exponent = -5
    };
    animation.Completed += (s, e) =>
    {
        // DO STUFF.
    };
    return animation;
}
```

Now, each of these animations work on their own, I can do

```
var animation = StartRectangleMarginAnimation(rectangle);
rectangle.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.MarginProperty, animation);
```

or

```
var animation = StartRectangleHeightAnimation(rectangle);
rectangle.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, animation);
```

But not both. As I understand it one animation "overwrites" the other. So we need a `Storyboard`, so. I have now

```
AnimationTimeline shrink = StartRectangleHeightAnimation(rectangle);
AnimationTimeline move = StartRectangleMarginAnimation(rectangle);

Storyboard.SetTarget(shrink, rectangle);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(shrink, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.HeightProperty));

Storyboard.SetTarget(move, rectangle);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(move, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.MarginProperty));

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(shrink);
storyboard.Children.Add(move);
storyboard.Begin(this);
```

But this animates height, but not margin. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code works fine, ensure that thickness in your StartRectangleMarginAnimation is valid (no negative values). Note that your easing function is not smooth (exponent -5) so slow down your both animations to 5 seconds (from 0.5) and you will see how it comes into play closer to the end (because of exponential ease with big negative exponent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Rectangle in my Window

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF4A4AE8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="44,69,100,50" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

and used this code :

```
  private AnimationTimeline StartRectangleMarginAnimation(Rectangle rectangle)
    {           
        Thickness t = new Thickness(rectangle.Margin.Left+20, rectangle.Margin.Top-50, rectangle.Margin.Right, rectangle.Margin.Bottom);

        ThicknessAnimation animation = new ThicknessAnimation(t, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        animation.EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase()
        {
            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut,
            Exponent = -5
        };
        animation.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            // DO STUFF.
        };
        return animation;
    }
    private AnimationTimeline StartRectangleHeightAnimation(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        return new DoubleAnimation(
            20,
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AnimationTimeline shrink = StartRectangleHeightAnimation(rectangle);
        AnimationTimeline move = StartRectangleMarginAnimation(rectangle);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(shrink, rectangle);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(shrink, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.HeightProperty));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(move, rectangle);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(move, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.MarginProperty));

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(shrink);
        storyboard.Children.Add(move);
        storyboard.Begin(this);
    }
```

Everything animated properly and simultaneously. I will remove this answer later on.